# How to define template or templateUrl (HTML) for a state with named views?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I was referring to [multiple named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) doc and found this statement in one of their examples:

[image]

Since the state "contacts.detail" has named views, its template or templateUrl will be ignored (as per the docs). So from where will contacts.detail.html be loaded/defined and how the 'info' view be targeted in that?

Answer (score 0):

They are using the following example in the documentation link you provided :

```
$stateProvider      
.state('contacts', {        
// This will get automatically plugged into the unnamed ui-view         
// of the parent state template. Since this is a top level state,       
// its parent state template is index.html.     
templateUrl: 'contacts.html'        
})      
.state('contacts.detail', {     
views: {        
    ////////////////////////////////////        
    // Relative Targeting             //        
    // Targets parent state ui-view's //        
    ////////////////////////////////////        

    // Relatively targets the 'detail' view in this state's parent state, 'contacts'.       
    // <div ui-view='detail'/> within contacts.html     
    "detail" : { },                 

    // Relatively targets the unnamed view in this state's parent state, 'contacts'.        
    // <div ui-view/> within contacts.html      
    "" : { },       

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////     
    // Absolute Targeting using '@'                      //     
    // Targets any view within this state or an ancestor //     
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////     

    // Absolutely targets the 'info' view in this state, 'contacts.detail'.     
    // <div ui-view='info'/> within contacts.detail.html        
    "info@contacts.detail" : { }        

    // Absolutely targets the 'detail' view in the 'contacts' state.        
    // <div ui-view='detail'/> within contacts.html     
    "detail@contacts" : { }     

    // Absolutely targets the unnamed view in parent 'contacts' state.      
    // <div ui-view/> within contacts.html      
    "@contacts" : { }       

    // absolutely targets the 'status' view in root unnamed state.      
    // <div ui-view='status'/> within index.html        
    "status@" : { }     

    // absolutely targets the unnamed view in root unnamed state.       
    // <div ui-view/> within index.html     
    "@" : { }       
});
```

Well detail is a child state of contact.

When you define that state, you can define it normally with tempalte url, or you can use nested views. If you use nested views, you shall have a parent state (here contact) and you have the choice to define the the detail child state with two ways :

```
    // Relatively targets the 'detail' view in this state's parent state, 'contacts'.       
// <div ui-view='detail'/> within contacts.html     
"detail" : {templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html' ...}
```

Which is the **relative way** (relative to its parent state, here 'contacts')

```
 // Absolutely targets the 'detail' view in the 'contacts' state.        
// <div ui-view='detail'/> within contacts.html     
"detail@contacts" : {templateUrl: 'contacts.details.html' }
```

Which is the **absolute way**, defining the detail child state.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8qj65to/) is an example of all of this.

Comment: Aren't these "views" independent of each other? I mean, from what I understood from your comment, "info@contacts.detail" depends on "detail" view to load its template in ui-view='info'. 
The examples above are just to make us understand different flavors of absolute vs relative targeting.

Comment: Sorry I realized my first answer was not clear, you can see my edits, if it's not clear enought, ask again and I will try to make a fiddle

Comment: Thank you, however, I'm afraid I believe I'm not clear in communicating what my exact question is. My question is specific to 'info@contacts.detail'. Remove all of the views declaration from 'contacts.detail' state and keep only 'info@contacts.detail'. And you have <div ui-view='info'/> within contacts.detail.html. I need to understand how will you work with this setup? A fiddle would be great.

Comment: I just added the fiddle to sum it up